# using ag grid enterprise version to implement expand or collapse

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I am trying to change a ***at grid*** to ***ag grid***. I am using the Enterprise version.The data structure is like this:

```
let data=[
  { name: "T-001", attribute: "VOL", plantValue: 71, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~7d428201009c3318060a0000" },
  { name: "T-001", attribute: "Amenam", plantValue: 72, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~7d428201009c3318060a0000" },
  { name: "T-001", attribute: "Arab Light", plantValue: 71, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~7d428201009c3318060a0000" },
  { name: "T-002", attribute: "VOL", plantValue: 21, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~bb4a8201009c3318060d0000" },
  { name: "T-002", attribute: "Amenam", plantValue: 45, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~bb4a8201009c3318060d0000" },
  { name: "T-002", attribute: "Arab Light", plantValue: 54, scheduleValue: 71, baselineValue: 71, newBaselineTime: "2020-01-17T08:30:00+08:00", id: "~bb4a8201009c3318060d0000" },
];
```

Is it possible to make it like this:[grid picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yQV6.png).
So the column ***tank*** can expand or collapse under the same tank name like it does in ***at grid***.
Since the ***tank*** has the same name, I have used tree data feature, but that does not work. However grouping by the column ***tank*** doesn't look like the original ***at grid***. Neither tree data or group works for me.

```
let gridOptions= {
  treeData: true, 
  groupDefaultExpanded: -1, 
  getDataPath: function(data) {
    return data.orgHierarchy;
  };
autoGroupColumnDef:{
  headerName: 'Tank',
  tooltipField:"name",
  pinned: true,
  lockPosition: true,
  headerCheckboxSelection: true,
  headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
  checkboxSelection: true,
  cellRendererParams: {
  suppressCount: true
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need tree data for this type of grouping behavior. Simply use row grouping feature of ag-grid.

Firstly, mark your column name to be the one to group by by specifying `rowGroup : true` for that column.

This will however create an additional group column and also display name column. So you will have to hide your name column by setting `hide : true`.

Finally you can customize the group column to have a custom name and pass this to `gridOptions`

```
autoGroupColumnDef:{
  headerName: 'Tank',
  tooltipField:"name",
  pinned: true,
  lockPosition: true,
  headerCheckboxSelection: true,
  headerCheckboxSelectionFilteredOnly: true,
  checkboxSelection: true,
  cellRendererParams: {
  suppressCount: true
  }
},
```